# Verify Github webhook signature

Tags: c#, sha256, github-webhook, github-app, smee

I'm trying to build a Github app backed by a handler in C#. In order to test the code on your local device, you can use [smee.io](https://smee.io). In the code you use the .NET `SmeeClient` which establishes a connection to the server and downstreams payloads to your .NET application. In [Probot](https://github.com/probot/probot) it's setup by default like this, but the code is spread over several repositories. I'm trying to build something similar in .NET now.

The code is hosted [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.GithubApps), the modifications to verify the signature are [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.GithubApps/tree/handle-secrets).

I've written a small code snippet to simplify the verification of the signature during testing:

```
var receivedFromGithub = "sha256=4eadd8e53ec9e1377084c243f7bc103de7dd7171948d2acee3d06c20154dceb5";
var configuredSecret = "[not-going-to-share-this]";
var rawBody = """
    {"event":"issues","payload":{"action":"opened","issue":{"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/issues/24","repository_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst","labels_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/issues/24/labels{/name}","comments_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/issues/24/comments","events_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/issues/24/events","html_url":"https://github.com/Example/tsst/issues/24","id":2096820864,"node_id":"I_kwDOLHq9zc58-vKA","number":24,"title":"Test 23","user":{"login":"Example","id":9629574,"node_id":"MDQ6VXNlcjk2Mjk1NzQ=","avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/9629574?v=4","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example","html_url":"https://github.com/Example","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false},"labels":[],"state":"open","locked":false,"assignee":null,"assignees":[],"milestone":null,"comments":0,"created_at":"2024-01-23T19:19:44Z","updated_at":"2024-01-23T19:19:44Z","closed_at":null,"author_association":"OWNER","active_lock_reason":null,"body":null,"reactions":{"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/issues/24/reactions","total_count":0,"+1":0,"-1":0,"laugh":0,"hooray":0,"confused":0,"heart":0,"rocket":0,"eyes":0},"timeline_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/issues/24/timeline","performed_via_github_app":null,"state_reason":null},"repository":{"id":746241485,"node_id":"R_kgDOLHq9zQ","name":"tsst","full_name":"Example/tsst","private":false,"owner":{"login":"Example","id":9629574,"node_id":"MDQ6VXNlcjk2Mjk1NzQ=","avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/9629574?v=4","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example","html_url":"https://github.com/Example","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false},"html_url":"https://github.com/Example/tsst","description":null,"fork":false,"url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst","forks_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/forks","keys_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/keys{/key_id}","collaborators_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/collaborators{/collaborator}","teams_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/teams","hooks_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/hooks","issue_events_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/issues/events{/number}","events_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/events","assignees_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/assignees{/user}","branches_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/branches{/branch}","tags_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/tags","blobs_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/git/blobs{/sha}","git_tags_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/git/tags{/sha}","git_refs_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/git/refs{/sha}","trees_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/git/trees{/sha}","statuses_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/statuses/{sha}","languages_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/languages","stargazers_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/stargazers","contributors_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/contributors","subscribers_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/subscribers","subscription_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/subscription","commits_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/commits{/sha}","git_commits_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/git/commits{/sha}","comments_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/comments{/number}","issue_comment_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/issues/comments{/number}","contents_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/contents/{+path}","compare_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/compare/{base}...{head}","merges_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/merges","archive_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/{archive_format}{/ref}","downloads_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/downloads","issues_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/issues{/number}","pulls_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/pulls{/number}","milestones_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/milestones{/number}","notifications_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/notifications{?since,all,participating}","labels_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/labels{/name}","releases_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/releases{/id}","deployments_url":"https://api.github.com/repos/Example/tsst/deployments","created_at":"2024-01-21T13:50:49Z","updated_at":"2024-01-21T13:50:49Z","pushed_at":"2024-01-21T13:50:49Z","git_url":"git://github.com/Example/tsst.git","ssh_url":"git@github.com:Example/tsst.git","clone_url":"https://github.com/Example/tsst.git","svn_url":"https://github.com/Example/tsst","homepage":null,"size":0,"stargazers_count":0,"watchers_count":0,"language":null,"has_issues":true,"has_projects":true,"has_downloads":true,"has_wiki":true,"has_pages":false,"has_discussions":false,"forks_count":0,"mirror_url":null,"archived":false,"disabled":false,"open_issues_count":23,"license":null,"allow_forking":true,"is_template":false,"web_commit_signoff_required":false,"topics":[],"visibility":"public","forks":0,"open_issues":23,"watchers":0,"default_branch":"main"},"sender":{"login":"Example","id":9629574,"node_id":"MDQ6VXNlcjk2Mjk1NzQ=","avatar_url":"https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/9629574?v=4","gravatar_id":"","url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example","html_url":"https://github.com/Example","followers_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/followers","following_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/following{/other_user}","gists_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/gists{/gist_id}","starred_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/starred{/owner}{/repo}","subscriptions_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/subscriptions","organizations_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/orgs","repos_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/repos","events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/events{/privacy}","received_events_url":"https://api.github.com/users/Example/received_events","type":"User","site_admin":false},"installation":{"id":46383717,"node_id":"MDIzOkludGVncmF0aW9uSW5zdGFsbGF0aW9uNDYzODM3MTc="}}}
    """;




// Re-compute the hash value using the secret as the key.
byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuredSecret);
using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(key))
{
    {
        // Use secret to re-compute the hash of the payload.
        byte[] computedSig = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawBody));
        // Notice the hash needs to be in HEX before comparison
        Console.WriteLine("Computed signature: {0}", ToHexString(computedSig));
    }
}

static string ToHexString(byte[] bytes)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in bytes)
    {
        builder.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

However, no matter what encoding (`UTF-8`, `ASCII`) or `SHA` crypt I use, I always get other results. I litterally copied the payload from the smee-channel-url when it appears.

How can I correctly verify this signature from github in c#? Do I need the request body to verify the signature?

### EDIT

Okay, according to [this documentation link](https://docs.github.com/en/webhooks/using-webhooks/validating-webhook-deliveries#testing-the-webhook-payload-validation), the following code snippet gives the desired result:

```
var rawBody = "Hello, World!";
var signatureSha256 = "757107ea0eb2509fc211221cce984b8a37570b6d7586c22c46f4379c8b043e17";
var secret = "It's a Secret to Everybody";
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(secret))
{
    var keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);
    var bodyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawBody);

    var hash = HMACSHA256.HashData(keyBytes, bodyBytes);
    var hashHex = Convert.ToHexString(hash);
    var expectedHeader = hashHex.ToLower(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var correct = (signatureSha256.ToString() == expectedHeader); // true
}
```

### EDIT 2

Okay, with the latest state of the code, I managed to get the correct signature for basic issue titles, but it fails when the title contains special characters.

So for the snippet:

```cs
var rawBody = """
    {"title": "Test 67 = with - more + characters : and . colons"}
    """;

using var ms = new MemoryStream();
using var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(ms);
JsonDocument.Parse(rawBody!).WriteTo(writer);

await writer.FlushAsync();
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
using var reader = new StreamReader(ms);
var jsonFormatted = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

Console.WriteLine(jsonFormatted);
// {"title":"Test 67 = with - more \u002B characters : and . colons"}
```

If I can find a solution to this, the problem is solved.

Comment: Hi, instead of voting to close, you'd better leave a constructive comment

Comment: I replaced all code from the second snippet with just [this single line](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.GithubApps/blob/master/MintPlayer.GithubApps%2FSmeeExtensions.cs#L13) and now it works as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the formatting of the JSON. When I read the payload from the SMEE channel, the JSON is formatted and not the same as the JSON that was actually sent.

Solution was to format the JSON using

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data.Body.ToString()));
```

Now the signature matches the payload.